# Issue creating HttpClient helper method

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a functioning async Task that calls a web service:

```
private async Task GetResult()
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", _username);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Action", "GET");
      /* etc */
      var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
   }
}
```

I would like to separate out the creation of the HttpClient object so it can be parameterized and reused:

```
private async Task GetResult()
{
   using (var client = GetClient(_baseAddress, _username))
   {
      var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
   }
}
private static HttpClient GetClient(string Address, string Username)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Address);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", Username);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Action", "GET");
      /* etc */
      return client;
   }
}
```

While this appears functionally identical to me, the latter throws an `AggregateException` error with inner exception

> Cannot Access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.

Perhaps there is some async subtlety that I don't understand?

Comment: I've updated title to clarify problem - feel free to rollback.

Comment: Looks good. I couldn't come up with the right verbiage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the `using` inside of `GetClient`. You only use `using` for things that remain "in your ownership", you are "giving up ownership to the caller" when you `return client;`.

It is now the caller's resposability to use a `using` statement (which you do already correctly do in `GetResult`).

This has nothing to do with asnyc and is simply standard `IDisposable` behavior.

Comment: So simple, go figure!